# systemd-coredump - Invalid argument

Tags: linux, systemd, core-dump

I'm trying to force a core dump using systemd-coredump, however, when I check my journal I see the following error:

> systemd-coredump@7-3897-0.service: Failed at step NETWORK spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-coredump: Invalid argument

and `coredumpctl` reports no cores.

My core_pattern is:

```
|/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %e
```

/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump does exist and is executable.
I have noticed that in the /etc/systemd/coredump.conf, everything is commented out.

```
[Coredump]
#Storage=external
#Compress=yes
#ProcessSizeMax=2G
#ExternalSizeMax=2G
#JournalSizeMax=767M
#MaxUse=
#KeepFree=
```

...which strikes me as odd...

Is there a way of "previewing" the arguments from core_pattern having been expanded that are fed into systemd-coredump - that way I could see if there is anything odd going on there... Otherwise, any idea what the problem could be?

**Edit**

I've also tried setting the core_pattern to point to a file like

```
bash -c 'echo "/home/root/core.%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern'
```

and

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

But that doesn't work either - the core file doesn't get created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a core out of this (I think!) with a workaround. This still doesn't  answer the question but at least gets me over this hump.

I created my own script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo $@ > /home/root/arguments.txt

if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    echo "Data was piped to this script!" >> /home/root/arguments.txt
    cat > /home/root/core.bin 
else
    echo "No data received" >> /home/root/arguments.txt
fi
```

And set the core_pattern to pipe through this script rather than `systemd-coredump`

This allows me to both see the arguments passed into the script (so it does answer that part of the question!) contained in `arguments.txt` and the core itself is written to `core.bin`

(At least I think it's the core - it's not giving me a huge amount of info but I'm a bit of a newbie at gdb so that could be the reason.)